# Why i cannot add object to the following array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why i cannot add object to the following array?

```
var userNames = {};
var input = $(this).text();
console.log('input=' + input); //success
userNames.push(input);
```

Comment: An array initializer looks like this: `[]`. What you've got is an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var userNames = [];
var input = $(this).text();
console.log('input=' + input); //success
userNames.push(input);
```